# Template inheritance in C++ (porting Java code)

Tags: java, c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

I would like to port a Java programm to C++ which is using generics in one class.

```
public class Graph<T extends Node> {
  ...
}
```

I already stumpled across this problem a couple years ago and couldn't solve it because C++ does not support this in those days. Is this now possible in C++11 or is there any method to force the compiler to check if the generic type has the baseclass Node inherited?

```
template <typename T : public Node>
class Graph {
  ...
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ThePlatypus How is that forum thread on nested template classes in any way related to this question?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there any method to force the compiler to check if the generic type has the baseclass Node inherited?

You are looking for [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). Now, to make it a compile time check, you could use it with [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

In my opinion, it is a matter of judgment whether to enforce that `T` must derive from `Node`. If `T` implements all the necessary methods so that the `Graph` class compiles, I see no reason to enforce that `T` must be derived from `Node`.

Comment: +1 for not enforcing it. C++ is not Java and doesn't need the crutches Java provides.

Comment: Uhm, aren't concepts kinda for doing this?

Comment: @Skeen Yes, ultimately concepts will be the solution. However, in C++11 this is probably the closest you can do.